# Unknown Process Openfire Java Run Time Error - Possible Memory Leak?

Tags: java, jvm, openfire

I have a unknown error log in my root folder namely

```
hs_err_pidxxx.log
```

Inside there i have following i dont know how to fix this or which service is actually doing log. I think its java VM error, i run openfire as a service, which may be the cause,

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 32756 bytes for ChunkPool::allocate
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (allocation.cpp:211), pid=15471, tid=2920495984
#
# JRE version: 6.0_41-b02
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (20.14-b01 mixed mode linux-x86 )

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0xf67e8c00):  VMThread [stack: 0xae0b3000,0xae134000] [id=15487]

Stack: [0xae0b3000,0xae134000],  sp=0xae1328a0,  free space=510k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x727990]
```

Is there anyone know how to fix this issue ?i already allocated about 2GB memory for the JVM heapsize and 2.8 GB for the java thread size..

OPENFIRE_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx2650m"

Comment: You can post your JVM params to get more information

Comment: OPENFIRE_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx2650m"

Comment: Have you tried with posible solutions that appear in the log file? Personaly, in some situations I have had to use the "Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)" param. Maybe it can help you if your application managed a large number of threads

Comment: I did but real problem seems to be it keep on restarting from time to time with error "Caught exception: String could not be parsed as XML"